# trying to install Grunt locally

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to install Grunt locally and after typing the following:

npm install grunt-cli --save-dev

I get the following errors:

[image]

Do I need to change some network settings?

Comment: Do you have a proxy running ?

Comment: Yes, I have been told by the IT adminstrator that it's something to do with Grunt config... I believe to be a proxy related issue...

Comment: I think it's more npm config which is problematic here. You can display you're current config with `npm config list`. You can also see it in the .npmrc file located in your user directory. You might be missing the config properties `proxy` and/or `https-proxy`.